# java ui component to represent calendar in tabular form

Tags: java

I would like to show the calendar in the tabular form with weeks and days.
Any suggestion on which component/library i can use?

Thanks in advance,
Shags

Answer (score 0):

Try it using javafx
[Calendar](http://javafx.com/samples/Calendar/)